# Calling a function with no arguments in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

How do I call a function with no arguments in CoffeeScript without parens?

```
fun = -> alert "Boo!"
```

I have tried `fun.` and `(fun)`

Comment: Parentheses are merely optional when the usage is *unambiguous in context*. When it is ambiguous, just write regular Javascript syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
fun = -> alert "Boo!"
do fun
```

It is shorthand syntax for calling functions that are declared in-place.

```
someVar = do -> #some code...
```

Comment: Please note that you however can't call this function later, like `someVar()`

Comment: someVar contains result of the function. If you want function and result, you can do: `someVar = do fun = ->`

Answer (score 11):

You should write `fun()`

It is just like you do in javascript

If you write just `fun` in for example `foo=fun` , coffeescript will think it is just the `fun` variable (because there's no way to differentiate between a function call and a simple variable).

You can also use arguments inside the parenthesis, with `fun(arg)`, but the "official syntax" when you call a function with arguments is `fun arg`

Comment: I know that but it's not satisfactory

Comment: What would you like more ?